# pdf.js - Return angular promise instead of javascript promise

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, angular-promise, pdf.js

I am using pdf.js. I want to write a wrapper that returns angular promise instead of the native javascript promise returned by pdf.js. Here is my code so far.

```
this.hasPassword = function (url) {
  return PDFJS.getDocument(url, null, null, null).then(function (res) {
    if (res.pdfInfo) {
      return false;
    }

    return true;
  }, function (err) {
    return true;
  });
};
```

This return's a javascript promise. How do I make it return angular promise. Can I use $q.defer() and resolve it and return angular promise?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to do smth like this:

```
function (url) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    PDFJS.getDocument(url, null, null, null).then(function (res) {
        if (res.pdfInfo) {
            deferred.resolve(false);
        }
        deferred.resolve(true);
    }, function (err) {
        deferred.reject(true);
    });
    return deferred.promise;
};
```